# Web Page Not Available on StraightTalk Android ZTE

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, browser, zte-merit

I have a [StraightTalk ZTE Merit](http://www.walmart.com/ip/Straight-Talk-ZTE-Merit-Z990G-Prepaid-Cell-Phone/20933055), and the browser keeps on saying "web page not available".

`Data enabled` and `Data roaming` are both checked under `Mobile network settings`. For some reason, it will not let me edit the APN settings.

I cannot use any internet-based apps.

This is the third day it has been like this.

Any help would be great.

***Some troubleshooting results***:

- Cellular network is AT&T, MVNO is StraightTalk.
- Voice/Text still works.
- No installation of apps prior to the issue
- Have cleared the Browser's cookies and cache
- It has worked on previous occasion
- Disabling data roaming did not seem to help
- Does not work over Wifi
- APN is set to:

  - Name is WAP.

    - APN is att.mnvo
    - Proxy is proxy.mnvo.tracfone.com
    - Port is 80
    - MMSC is mmsc.cingular.com
    - MMMS proxy is proxy.tracfone.com
    - MMS port is 80
    - MCC is 310
    - MNC is 410
    - Authentication type is none
    - APN type is *default,mms,supl*
  - Am suspecting the proxy within the APN setting, could be the fault, or that the service provider has changed something somewhere.

OP was advised to check with their cellular network's web-site to see if there's a page somewhere, (*it would require registering details such as name/email/number*) and perhaps a button to send the APN details via SMS.

Answer (score -1):

Proxy.mvno.tracfone.com  make sure that the letter P is on upper case
and this is an old apn settings 
your internet is slow on this kind of apn
use the current LTE one

Comment: Hostnames are not case sensitive. Can you suggest the specific APN settings the OP should be using?